# How switch the grub from 15.04 to 14.04 in a system which has installed both

Tags: 14.04, grub2, 15.04

I have installed ubuntu 15.04 and 14.04. 
First i had installed 14.04 after that i installed 15.04 and the grub boot menu changed to 15.04.
Now i want to revert it, that means i want to change the grub that appears on startup to grub of 14.04.
How to do it?

Comment: How the "shift" key during boot to show the grub menu and pick another option to boot from. See for instance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Comment: My grub menu is appearing fine. Order is also fine but the problem is I want the grub linked with 14.04 to appear on startup rather than 15.04.

Comment: Boot to 14.04, then open terminal and run command `sudo grub-install sdX`  Replace the `X` with your drive-letter, if you have only one drive it will be likely `sudo grub-install sda`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `/etc/default/grub`, you have a variable `GRUB_DEFAULT`:

```
↳ grep GRUB_DEFAULT /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

This is the menu entry that will be used by default. To see which menu entries you have, have a look in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (`nl -v 0` is used to add the line numbers):

```
↳ egrep "^menuentry |^submenu " /boot/grub/grub.cfg | nl -v 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 0  menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-bf88b0d6-7f16-4314-87f5-ce3e84a6a396' {
 1  submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-bf88b0d6-7f16-4314-87f5-ce3e84a6a396' {
 2  menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

Having `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` means booting the first `menuentry`. So if you wanted to boot to `System setup` by default (as a silly example), set `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` and run `sudo update-grub`.

In the case you want to boot something in the `submenu` by default, you'd have to use the `submenu` index, `>` and the index of the `menuentry` in the submenu. E.g, 4th entry in `submenu`, then `GRUB_DEFAULT` should be set to `"1>3"`

It is also possible to set `GRUB_DEFAULT` to name label of a `menuentry` (first parameter), so `GRUB_DEFAULT='System setup'` would also be a valid setting.

Whenever changing `/etc/default/grub`, do not forget to run `sudo update-grub`.

More reading at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus.

Comment: I dont want to change the order of grub menu. I want to change the grub that appears on startup to grub of 14.04. Currently grub of 15.04 is installed.

Comment: I interpret that as you want to change the default boot option from 15.04 to 14.04? Then the easiest way would be to change `GRUB_DEFAULT`.

Comment: No. I dont want to do that. I dont want the ubuntu 15.04 anymore and want to delete it. But if I delete it I will get grub rescue error. So I thought to change the grub to 14.04 first.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79813/how-to-remove-a-second-ubuntu-install

Comment: I did what was said in above link and ran into the problem of grub rescue :(